# How to make a temporary variable's pointer valid in the future?

Tags: c++

I have a project, which receives data from a socket, then handles it and saves good data into a container.

I want high performance, so, i need to keep the copy operation less as i can.

here is my first code:

```
struct Data {  //  here is a demo, in real project, Data is a large struct
  int a;
  char b[20];
};  // data type

std::vector<const Data*> data_base;
void Handle(const Data& a) {
  if (a.good()) {  // only few data will get good
    data_base.emplace_back(&a); // data_map saved pointer to avoid copy
  }
}

int main() {
  while(true) {
    Data* a = new Data；// here waste memory, since only few data need to be saved
    socket.Recv(*a);
    Handle(*a);
  }
}
```

in this code, I saved data's pointer, so, the copy cost is saved.

But the problem is I `new` a lot of objects, which spends a lot of memory.

I have second design like this:

```
struct Data {
  int a;
  char b[20];
};  // data type

std::vector<const Data*> data_base;
void Handle(const Data& a) {
  if (a.good()) {  // only few data will get good
    // TODO: copy a's value to a permanent pointer, i don't know how to do that
  }
}

int main() {
  Data a;
  while(true) {
    socket.Recv(a);  // make a reusable
    Handle(*a);
  }
}
```

I think the second solution can save memory, and the performance wont be harmed. (no additional copy), am i right?

And how can I copy a temp variable into a pointer container(see TODO in solution 2)?

Comment: Your first code doesn't just waste memory, it has a memory leak since it's never freed. Eventually you'd run out of memory and the program would crash (or worse).

Comment: Is there any reason to store pointers? Please fix the mix `A` and `Data`.

Comment: yes, i will delete them all in other place. but i still need to keep those undeleted findable in my memory.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do any of that.

Do this instead:

```
struct Data {
  int a;
  char b[20];
};  // data type

std::vector<Data> data_base;
void Handle(const Data& a) {
  if (a.good()) {  // only few data will get good
    data_base.push_back(a);
  }
}

int main() {
  Data a;
  while(true) {
    socket.Recv(a);
    Handle(a);
  }
}
```

Copying your `Data` struct seems to be pretty trivial, and in any case you've stated that it will only happen rarely anyway. So the right thing to do is to optimize for the common case. Reuse the space for the data for receiving, and make a copy only when you need it.

Comment: sorry, this Data is a demo, in fact, my struct is very large, copy will cost a lot, i will add in my question describe

Comment: @cppdev If performance testing shows this to be a bottleneck, you have a few options. Maybe the objects are efficiently movable. Maybe you have a reasonable guess as to how many good elements there will be, so you can reserve space in the vector and read/write directly into the vector. Maybe you need to go back to the pointer-based approach (but please use smart pointers), while reusing the space of bad elements. All of these are possible, but more complicated, so you should definitely first measure performance.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> // TODO: copy a's value to a permant pointer, i dont know how to do that
> ```

You could do, it's just:

```
data_base.push_back(new Data(a))
```

But your code leaks memory. Use smart pointers:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Data>> data_base;
```

Anyway, I believe the intention is not to copy the data, but copy only pointers and only when needed. Use smart pointers anyway. I believe something along:

```
struct Data { int tmp; bool good(); };

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Data>> data_base;

void socket_recv(std::unique_ptr<A>& a);

void handle(std::unique_ptr<Data>& a) {
  if (a->good()) {  // only few data will get good
    data_base.emplace_back(std::move(a)); // we move the pointer around
    a = std::make_unique<Data>(); // allocate new memory for next run
  }
}

int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<Data> a = std::make_unique<Data>();
  while(true) {
    socket_recv(a);  // make a reusable
    handle(a);
  }
}
```

or using raw pointers:

```
std::vector<Data *> data_base;

void socket_recv(Data* a);

void handle(Data*& a) {
  if (a->good()) {  // only few data will get good
    data_base.push_back(a); // we move the pointer around
    a = new Data(); // allocate new memory for next run
  }
}

int main() {
  A *a = new Data();
  while(true) {
    socket_recv(a);  // make a reusable
    handle(a);
  }
  delete a;
}
```

Comment: sorry, i am new. is this fast? `move` will aviod copy?

Comment: It's moving pointers (i.e. moving `std::unique_ptr`), so, well, yes - pointers will be copied. Data should not be copied, only pointers to them. `is this fast?` No idea. [Rules of optimization](https://wiki.c2.com/?RulesOfOptimizationClub) - profile your code first.